# multi line text on windows phone application live tile

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

I am working on application live tile of windows phone and I want to show 4 5 lines in my tile like this

Line1
Line2
Line3
Line4
Line5

How I can show this on my application tile. as there is only one property to set this  `BackContent`

How I can acheive this in wp7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these blog posts:

http://vdcruijsen.net/2011/12/creating-dynamic-windows-phone-7-live-tile-images-client-side/

and

http://www.robfe.com/2012/02/building-on-the-fly-images-for-wp7-live-tiles/

Basically, make a user control that is 173 x 173 pixels. Use the Writeable Bitmap function to create an image of this control which is used as the image on the tile (front or back). You can add as much text in whatever format you need.

Comment: If you want the tile in the current wp7 theme colour, you have to generate a PNG file (with the accent colour as transparent). See this blog post for guidance: http://www.jayway.com/2012/04/03/advanced-transparent-live-tiles-with-count-for-windows-phone/

Answer (score 1):

Tested with 3 lines only:

```
BackContent = Line1 + Environment.NewLine + Line2 ... ;
```

Comment: It did the magic. I have tested till four lines. Can I reduce the font size and margins to fit the fifth line. Is that so any way...???